# Could $(2n-1)\left( \dfrac{1}{a}- \dfrac{1}{b} \right) $ be an integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, parity

Let $ a,b  \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \backslash \left \{ \tfrac{2N-1}{2M-1} : N,M \in \mathbb{N} \right \} $ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I want to prove that the quantity
\begin{equation}\label{key}
 (2n-1)\left( \dfrac{1}{a}- \dfrac{1}{b} \right) 
\end{equation}
cannot be an integer.

I got the following:

Assume that it is an integer, $N$, say. Then
\begin{equation}
 \dfrac{Nab}{a-b}
\end{equation}
is odd.
However, I get stuck here.

Comment: This is not clear.  What are $a,b$?  Arbitrary real numbers?  Rationals?  Something else?

Comment: "Neither a, nor can b, be written as a ratio of odd integers."..what is the exact meaning do you say, e.g. $a=\frac {2m}{2n-1}$ ?

Comment: @lulu $a,b$ can be real. It doesn't have to be rational.

Comment: In that case, your claim is false.  Let $a=\frac 1{\pi}$ and $b=\frac 1{\pi-1}$.

Comment: If you want a rational counterexample, take $a=\frac 34, b=\frac 32$.

Comment: What is $n$ I can not see?

Comment: For that matter, The integers $a=2,b=6$ already give a countexample.

Comment: @lulu I can't keep up with your pace. You continue to give counter-examples .. I'm still trying to understand the question.  :)

Comment: @lonestudent  Well, it's possible I have misunderstood the question, though it seems straight forward enough.  If I have, I trust the OP will explain why the three counterexamples I have proposed are somehow off the mark.

Comment: "odd plus odd is odd"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the expressions expressed need to be integer.

We can have $(2n-1)(\frac 1a - \frac 1b) = M\in \mathbb Z$

if $\frac 1a - \frac 1b = \frac M{2n-1}$

Nos $a,b$ can be *any* positive reals that are not a ration of two odd integers.

So we can have $b$ but any irrationa and then $a = \frac 1{\frac M{2n-1}-\frac 1b}$ will not be rational and that will work.

Example $b = \frac 1{\pi}$ and $a = \frac 1{2-\pi}$ and

$(2n-1)(\frac 1a -\frac 1b) = (2n-1)(2-\pi + \pi) = (2n-1)\cdot 2$ is an integer.

If we want $a$ and $b$ to be rational we can have $a$ and $b$ but have an even components.  Let $b = \frac 12$ and $a =\frac 14$.  Thn

$(2n-1)(\frac 1{\frac 14} - \frac 1{\frac 12})= (2n-1)(4-2) = 2(2n-1)$ is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a = b$.  Then the unnamed quantity is the integer $0$.

Possibly the strongest signal that your argument cannot work is your line "odd plus odd is odd", which is false.  The sum of two odd numbers is an even number.  Easy example: $1+1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are both odd integers, then $ab$ will be an odd integer. Then

1. $n= \frac{ab+1}{2}$ is an integer.
2. $\frac{2n-1}{a} = b$
3. $\frac{2n-1}{b} = a$
4. $(2n-1)\left( \dfrac{1}{a}- \dfrac{1}{b} \right) = b - a \in \Bbb Z$